# Can you use Versatile Evocation (Su) with Rime Spell (Metamagic)?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, feats, wizard

A player of mine wants to play to take [Admixture](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/arcane-schools/paizo---arcane-schools/classic-arcane-schools/evocation/admixture) which is a focused school under Evocation. He wants to combine take Versatile Evocation (Su) which comes under Admixture to cast Fireballs (for example) with [Rime Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/rime-spell-metamagic).

Rime Spell states that:

> This feat only affects spells with the cold descriptor.

And Versatile Evocation states that:

> This changes the descriptor of the spell to match the new energy type.

The question is that would casting a Fireball as a Cold using Versatile Evocation work with Rime Spell? I see no problem with it, but I require clarification. There are arguments made against it saying that Versatile Evocation modifies the spell after it as been cast while Rime Spell only works while it is being prepared.

Answer (score 9):

### Yes, you can

> This feat only **affects** spells with the cold descriptor.

The text doesn't say that you **can't** prepare a *Rime Fireball*, only that it **won't be affected**.
It is perfectly legitimate for your player's Wizard to prepare his *Rime Fireball* (with the required +1 level increase). During casting, he'll have the option to either:

1. Expand one of his *Admixture* daily uses to change it to a *Cold* spell, benefiting from the *Rime Spell* entangling effect.
2. Forgo the *Rime Spell* effect. and cast it as a normal fireball (or even as an *Acid* or *Shocking* spell, which may be useful against some exotic enemies or in special circumstances).

If he chooses the second option, the result is the same as if he simply used a 4th level spell slot to prepare a 3rd level spell - which is perfectly legitimate by the rules anyway.

---

**Further consideration:** The interpretation mentioned at the end of your question - stating that

> *Versatile Evocation* modifies the spell after it as been cast while *Rime Spell* only works while it is being prepared.
> <sub>(quoted from the **question**, **not the rules**)</sub>

This may lead to paradoxical results if used the other way around:
If *Rime Spell* is only concerned with the *Cold* descriptor during spell preparation, a wizard could prepare a *Rime Cone of Cold*, and later on, use *Admixture* to cast it as a *Fire* spell - resulting in a cone of flames with "frost that clings to the target, impeding it for a short time." - which is thematically ridiculous.

**Side Note:** Your player's wizard can always use a [Metamegic Rod](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods#TOC-Metamagic-Rods) of *Rime Spell* to apply this combo on-the-fly - this is relevant even with the harsher interpretation stating you can't prepare a non-cold spell with this feat.